# Why cant I convert this to double?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I display two decimal points after a number?

I have tried following:

```
var hrs = (from p in Hours.Where(h.UserName == UserName())
                              group p by p.Hours into g
                              select g.Sum(p => p.Hours)).Sum().ToString("#.##");

return Json(new { data = Convert.ToDouble(hrs).ToString("#.##") });
```

But it doesn't display anything on UI without `Convert.ToDouble()` and `ToString("#.##")` it displays hours "9"

How do we format results that we get by querying databases like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your input, they definitely helped in comming to the following soluion:

```
Decimal.Parse(hrs.ToString()).ToString("N2")
```

Efficient solution:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(hrs).ToString("N2")
```

Comment: Why are you converting to string, parsing back to double, just to re-convert to string?  What data type is `hrs`?

Comment: it is decimal. DB type: numeric(5,2)

Comment: @MattHouser Convert.ToDecimal(hrs).ToString("N2") works as well

Answer (score 2):

The result of your Linq query will be an `IEnumerabl<string>` (or `IQueryable<string>`). You'll need to do something like this:

```
var hrs = 
    (from p in Hours.Where(h.UserName == UserName())
     group p by p.Hours into g
     select g.Sum(p => p.Hours));

 return Json(new { data = hrs.Select(x => x.ToString("N2")) });
```

Answer (score 2):

ToString("N2") is used to show two decimal points

```
var hrs = (from p in Hours.Where(h.UserName == UserName())
                          group p by p.Hours into g
                          select g.Sum(p => p.Hours)).ToString("#.##");
return Json(new { data = Convert.ToDouble(hrs).ToString("N2") });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToDouble(hrs).ToString("f2")`

Answer (score 1):

The result of your query is not a single `double`, it is an `IEnumerable<double>` with one entry for each group your user is part of.

You'll want to add another `.Sum()` to your results (to get the sum of all groups your user is in).  From that, you can do `ToString("0.00")`.  You should also not need the extra `Convert()` and `ToString()`

```
var hrs = (from p in Hours.Where(h => h.UserName == UserName())
   group p by p.Hours into g
   select g.Sum(p => p.Hours)).Sum().ToString("0.00");

return Json(new { data = hrs });
```

**Edit:**

Changed `ToString("#.##")` to `ToString("0.00")`.  Alternatively, use `ToString("N2")`.

**Edit #2:**

Unless there is some reason for your grouping, I would streamline your LINQ statement and subsequent `Json` call to be:

```
var hrs = (from p in Hours
   where p.UserName == UserName()
   select p.Hours).Sum();

return Json(new { data = hrs.ToString("0.00") });
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add .Sum(), I have updated above. I get the following error after adding ToString("#.##"): No Overload for mehtod 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Updated my answer above.  Use `ToString("0.00")` instead of the `#` version.

Comment: I also think you can avoid the grouping by `p.Hours`

Comment: Removed 'GroupBy'. However adding anyting to "ToString()" gives me an error unless I convert it to decimal or double: No Overload for mehtod 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Json(new { data = Convert.ToDouble(hrs).ToString("N2") });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Json(new { data = String.Format("{0.00}",Convert.ToDouble(hrs))});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
return Json(new { data = Convert.ToDouble(hrs).ToString("#.00") });
```